# How can a vector of HashMaps be created and returned from main?

Tags: vector, hashmap, rust

I would like to create a vector of `HashMaps` in Rust. I have tried the following:

```
fn main() -> Vec<HashMap<String, String>> {
    let mut foo = HashMap::new();
    foo.insert("".to_string(), "".to_string());
    let f = Vec::new();
    f.push(foo);
    f
}
```

But I always get:

```
error[E0580]: main function has wrong type
  --> src/main.rs:9:1
   |
9  | / fn main() -> Vec<HashMap<String, String>> {
10 | |     let mut foo = HashMap::new();
11 | |     foo.insert("".to_string(), "".to_string());
12 | |     let f = Vec::new();
13 | |     f.push(foo);
14 | |     f
15 | | }
   | |_^ expected (), found struct `std::vec::Vec`
   |
   = note: expected type `fn()`
              found type `fn() -> std::vec::Vec<std::collections::HashMap<std::string::String, std::string::String>>`
```

Comment: Perhaps you could expand your question to explain what part of the error text "main function has wrong type" you found confusing? That way, we might be able to improve the compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You try to return a value from `fn main()`, which isn't possible.

It will work if you rename your function and call it from `main`:

```
fn create_map() -> Vec<HashMap<String, String>> {
    let mut foo = HashMap::new();
    foo.insert("".to_string(), "".to_string());
    let mut f = Vec::new();
    f.push(foo);
    f
}

fn main() {
    create_map();
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=f3116c7085964234ad95b0829ce9232a&version=stable)

However, you also forgot to add `mut` to `let f = Vec::new();`

Comment: Oh my gosh! Thank you, Tim!

Answer (score 2):

The compiler error has nothing to do with your vector or hashmap. It just states: "*main function has wrong type*". In Rust, every executable program starts at the function called `main` (located at the crate root). So that function name has a special meaning and a function called `main` at the crate root has to have a special signature (namely no arguments and `()` return type).

So you can fix the error by renaming your function and adding a `mut`. But you can write your code a bit more idiomatic with the `vec![]` macro:

```
fn get_vector() -> Vec<HashMap<String, String>> {
    let mut foo = HashMap::new();
    foo.insert("".to_string(), "".to_string());
    vec![foo]
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=12af968517dc19e2b08514eb208eba63&version=stable))